# A method to test for uniform distribution over a convex polytope

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, computational-geometry

Assuming I have a convex polytope defined as the intersection of $Ax=b$ and $x>0$ and I have a way to sample points from this object, is there a way I can test for uniformity of these sampled points? I would assume the use of the Chi-Squared test after first partitioning the space into equal area bins, but I'm not sure how I would go about doing that.

Comment: Cpt. Obvious comes to the rescue: For any part $A$ of your polytope $P$, the probability that a points lands in this part should be $\frac{|A|}{|P|}$. The finer parts, the better check.

Comment: I have no way of knowing $|P|$, in fact, this method is how I would calculate $|P|$, provided the sampling is uniform.

Comment: You have to know something ;-) For example, maybe you could construct a $n$-cube $C$ of known size such that $C \subset P$? Your polytope is convex, so if all corners of the cube satisfy your equations and inequalities, then the whole cube is inside.

Answer (score 0):

What sort of guarantee are you trying to achieve? If you're willing to test (whp) whether the distribution of those points in $N$ equal bins (the partition you decide to create) is either

- uniform
  vs
- $\epsilon$-far (in total variation distance, i.e. $L_1$ distance) from uniform

then you can do it with $\Theta(\frac{\sqrt{N}}{\epsilon^2}\ln\frac{1}{\delta})$ samples, and you will have the guarantee that, w.p. $1-\delta$,

- if it is uniform, then the test will pass;
- if the distribution has TV distance at least $\epsilon$ from the uniform distribution, it'll fail.

See for instance [[Pan08]](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~liam/research/abstracts/sparse-unif-test-abs.html).

Comment: (additionally, what sort of sampling access do you have — just "regular sampling", i.e. you get iid samples from the distribution $D$ you're trying to test, or can you somehow "tweak" the sampling to get elements distributed according to $D$ conditioned on them belonging to a specific part of your polytope?)

Comment: hit and run. Pick an initial point, choose a random direction, the next point is a random point between initial point and wall in that direction.

Comment: OK, I reckon that you only have "basic sampling" from the distribution this defines, then. I'm not sure how to do the partitioning in bins either — but provided you manage to get such partitioning, the approach above is likely to be the most efficient in terms of number of samples.